# Youtube API Yt.Player object not working with phonegap/on mobile [Yt player object vs. direct iframe]

Tags: iframe, youtube, cordova

i embedded my youtube player like this on my website:

```
<div id="player"> </div> 

var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {

          videoId: 'P2jViqMnnK4',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
             'onError': onError,

          },
          playerVars: {

                    'controls': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,
                },
        });
    }
```

now i´ve written a script which loads new youtube videos from a xml file.

I want to make a phonegap application with just this script playing youtube videos, but it isn´t working on android.

I´ve tested the other method of embedding it:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
 frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This works quite well, but i don´t know how to set the parameters i´ve set in the player object. And i don´t know how to connect my "changing script" with the direct iframe player.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a way to get the yt.player object working with phonegap/on mobile?
2. If not, how can i add my paramaters (i have in the yt.object player) to the direct iframe

thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok figured out how to add the parameters. ?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3

Comment: when you say it is not working, exactly what are you seeing? Is it a black screen with a key in top left corner?

Comment: did that solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to force the user to touch the youtube before anything else.
Once the user has actually touched the youtube player it can be used as normal.

I have worked around this by having the youtube player load up with an intro video. once the intro video plays then I can take control through the api.